# Multiple column UITableView (with cells not aligned)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How would you code the view as presented below ? there is two types of cells, the title headers, and the gray ones. all gray ones are the same type of `UITableViewCell` but their height varies.

[image]

This can have a very big number of items so the cells need to be recycled.

I'm thinking two `UITableViews` next to each other, sharing scroll events, The titles in the left one. and blank cells that i compute height to align starts of items in the new sections.

It's a bit complicated so I wanted to know if one of you have a better idea.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use a `UICollectionView` to create that type of UI.

Comment: Use UICollectionView Custom Layout
https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest